# How to reduce UIImage size to a maximum as possible

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I am using following code to resize the image.

[Resize a UIImage Right Way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

And I use interpolation quality as kCGInterpolationLow.

And then I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.0) to get the NSData of that image.

Still its a little bit high in size around 100kb. when I send it over the network. Can I reduce it further. If I am to reduce it more what could I do ?

Thanks and Kind Regards,

Comment: Did you find an answer to this problem?  I have the exact same issue - I have followed Trevors bike shed solution and used UIImageJPEGRepresentation but I still have quite big image files (also about 100kb) - I think they should be about 1/4 of this size.
Many thanks

Comment: In my case, Finally I did something like this. Save the image in UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.5).. and then when I recreate I use UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1).. so the quality doesn't look really bad. Actually I couldn't come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

you image compress and image data stroed NSData format. The function is

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage * _Nonnull image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

Example:

```
NSData *objImgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(objImg,1.0);
```